# android LocationListener not stopping GPS use

Tags: android, service, gps, locationlistener, location-provider

In my `service`, in some scenarios I can't stop the GPS from searching and draining the device battery.

*LocationListenerAgent.java*

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    thisContext = this;
    // Register ourselves for location updates

    networkListener = new LocationListenerAgent();
    gpsListener = new LocationListenerAgent();

    lmgrNet = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lmgrGps = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    gps_enabled = lmgrGps.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    lmgrNet.requestLocationUpdates("network", ONE_MINUTE, 10, networkListener);
    lmgrGps.requestLocationUpdates("gps", ONE_MINUTE, 10, gpsListener);

    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    // Unregister listener
    lmgrNet.removeUpdates(this);
    lmgrNet = null;
    lmgrGps.removeUpdates(this);
    lmgrGps = null;
}
```

From some places in my app when I press "back" on the main activity, which destroys the app, this is called:

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    if (mBound) {
        unbindService(mConnection); //this is a callback to the locationlisteneragent class to bind it to a service
        mBound = false;
    }
    super.onStop();
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    if (mBound) {
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mBound = false;
    }
    stopService(new Intent(this, LocationListenerAgent.class));
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

maybe my `super.On` lifecycle methods need to be before the code with the method.

What else do I need to do to stop the GPS??? I've seen other people having problems with this and the answers don't seem so absolute.

In other scenarios in my app, the GPS does stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my issue. I know I didn't mention mapview in the original post but if you are also using MapView the solution is that mapview can use a GPS service unrelated to your own gps location listening service.

In your mapview

`private MyLocationOverlay currLocationOverlay;`

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    if(currLocationOverlay!=null)
        currLocationOverlay.disableMyLocation();
    super.onStop();
}
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if(currLocationOverlay!=null)
        currLocationOverlay.disableMyLocation();
    stopService(new Intent(this, LocationListenerAgent.class));
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code you posted, I think you are not removing the location updates.

In your onDestroy() method it should be:

```
lmgrNet.removeUpdates(networkListener);
lmgrNet.removeUpdates(gpsListener);
```

Comment: I am removing location updates, look again. But I solved it, thank you.

Comment: My fault. If LocationListenerAgent is your Service, why are you creating 2 additional objects for the listeners instead of using `this`? Also I think you don't need 2 different LocationManagers for the different providers.

Comment: I tried both ways. I actually separated the listeners because another answer on this site suggested that "removeUpdates" doesn't remove all listeners, and a solution for that issue would be put the providers in different locationmanagers, I hope that makes sense but you can see what I did in my code

Answer (score 0):

You can Also Stop like this

stopService(new Intent(AlertsActivity.this,PollingService.class));                                                          android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());