# How to stop custom android service?

Tags: android, service

I have a service:

```
[Service]
public class LocationService : Service, ILocationListener
{
....

public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(...)
{ return StartCommandResult.Sticky; } 
}
```

Started in one of environment

```
new Task(() =>
{
Application.Context.StartService(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(LocationService)));
}).Start();
```

**How to stop this service from another place?**

I tried to do this:

```
Application.Context.StopService(new Intent(Application.Context, typeof(LocationService)));
```

but it does not always work

Comment: In what cases does it not seem to be working?

Comment: random case. its background gps-servoce. Sometimes it stops and sometimes not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These possible duplicates might solve your issue:

[android LocationListener not stopping GPS use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496336/android-locationlistener-not-stopping-gps-use)

[android how to stop gps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2012870/android-how-to-stop-gps)

Sounds like the big thing is making sure nothing is still requesting location updates.

Answer (score 0):

the answer was here:

[Stop Location Listener in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894234/stop-location-listener-in-android)

In my case its call method *StopLocationUpdates*

```
[Service]
public class LocationService : Service, ILocationListener
{
....

public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(...)
{ 
     return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
} 

public void StopLocationUpdates()
{
    LocManager.RemoveUpdates(this);
    LocManager= null;
}

}
```